# Named connection not intended for EntityClient?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure, ado.net, web-config

In trying to connect to an Azure database server from an MVC application, I'm getting the error:

> The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.

which by virtue of being overly broad is most unhelpful.  is there any way I can narrow down which of these 3 cases it is that I'm dealing with?

Comment: Please provide your connection string and DbContext